# how to read printers at client machine (either by JS or VbS or read windows registery)

Tags: javascript, .net, printing, vbscript, registry

I need a solution to read all the printers on web client computer and show them into a dropdown list.

Printer name is needed for back-end printing for the specific user based on printer selected and saved into DB.

I know many of u going to say bad design or not a good idea to read registry......

Noting is a bad design, it's all based on certain requirement and business need.
Also application is only for IE on Windows and with in intranet and have security excemption and added under trusted site in organization.

Reading registry by JavaScript or by System.Management class is needed

Comment: What do you have so far that isn't working?

Comment: I don't have full solution? all I need is the way to read the aviable printers from client's machine (registry) and then show them in my webpage....